# Java: Efficient way to search ArrayList of objects for matching ids but different fields

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency, java-stream

Suppose I have a large (> 100,000,000) ArrayList of Person, where Person is defined as:

```
class Person {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

I am trying to write a method, `hasDuplicatePersonsWithDifferentNames()` that returns `true` if the `ArrayList` contains elements with equal ids but different names. For example:

**This would return true, because there are two equal ids with different names**

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person(1, "bob");
people.add(new Person(1, "alice");
```

**This would return false, because while there two equal ids, they share the same names**

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person(1, "bob");
people.add(new Person(1, "bob");
```

I was thinking there would be some way to utilize Java Streams, which are known to be efficient, or possibly even concurrency. But I can't find an example of either. I know I could use a dictionary and solve this in `O(n)` time/space, but I believe with streams/concurrency I could possibly save on the space complexity.

Comment: Based on the schema that you have shared if you have proper `equals` and `hashCode` overridden for this object. You can transform the data into a HashSet and compare the size of the initial list and final set. If not, then you can use a `Map` with `id` as key and `name`s as values, when you find an existing key in the map, you would return `true`. You cannot resolve this in less than `O(n)` runtime as the worst case(consider the first and the last element in an iteration to be duplicate). With concurrency hopefully, the only thing that you might be looking forward to is distributed execution.

Comment: You can try `toConcurrentMap`, mapping ID to key and name to value, with a merge function that compares the old value and the new value. If they are the same, set a false atomic boolean to true. And at the end, check that atomic boolean. The downside is that this is not short-circuiting...

Comment: When you want to save space you have to give up time. Sort your List with a Comparator that takes id and name into account. Afterwards  you just have to go over the list again and compare one element with the next. Fixed space, but O(n log(n)) time.

Comment: (Please add more context: If there was no good reason to have multiple names for a single ID in the first place, it was a good idea to use a `Set` rather than a `List` - *unless* indexed access was required.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you that wrong kind of data structure.

If you use a list, then searching the list for something involves iterating the list.  In you case, that means (potentially) testing each and every element of the list.  All 100 million of them.

Using streams or concurrency won't help.  You code still has to test 100 million entries.  (OK, parallel search could give you a `P`-fold speed up, where `P` is the number of physical cores available.  But `P` is going to be small and constant.)

So if you want to do better than `O(N)` ... where `N` is a very large number ... you need a data structure that supports lookup based on element fields.  Here are some possibilities:

- Use a `Map<Integer, Person>` and populate it as a mapping from `id` to `Person`.  The problem is that a `Map` can only hold one value for each key, so you couldn't actually store Bob and Alice in the map at the same time.  (But that might be a better solution than what you are currently doing.)

  It you use `HashMap`, operations like insertion deletion and lookup are `O(1)`.
- Use a multi-map.  Both Apache Commons and Guava provide multi-map classes, or you could us a `Map<Integer, List<Person>>`.
- Both of the above use a lot more memory than an `ArrayList`.  Another option would be to keep your list ordered on the `id` values of the `Person` objects, so that you can perform a binary search.